# In iterm I can't put directly some characters like ~ or "

Tags: keyboard, terminal, iterm

When I try to put characters like " or ~ in iterm it gets underscores and waits for next one to be finally put, how I can stop it?

Comment: What keyboard and mapping are you using?

Comment: It sounds like the us international PC layout may be active and needs to be changed to us.